# Why does this Python program involving CSV files not repeat?

Tags: python, csv

It works PERFECTLY... once...

Idea is to take a list of names from a text file (each on a new line) and create a new CSV file based on whether or not the line starts with the text name.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import csv

lines = []
with open('output.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        lines.append(line[:-1])

with open('corrected.csv','w') as correct:
    writer = csv.writer(correct, dialect = 'excel')
    with open('input.csv', 'r') as mycsv:
        reader = csv.reader(mycsv)
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] in lines:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

The problem is that it quits after doing it once. I've checked the data and it goes through properly and perfectly appends the line of data to the new CSV file... but it won't continue after one. I've played around with while loops, but I got a LOT of help from SO users to build this and don't really know what I need to mess around with.

If I'm being too vague, or too needy, please do let me know. Thank you for any and all help received!

EXAMPLE!

```
output.txt
/category/apples
/category/oranges
/category/brussel-sprouts
/category/zuccini
/category/passion-fruit


input.csv
/category/apples, 500, 45%, 345
/category/oranges, 345, 54%, 432
/category/brussel-sprouts, 435, 45%, 456
/category/zuccini, 345, 43%, 345
/category/passion-fruit, 364, 23%, 475


corrected.csv
/category/apples, 500, 45%, 345
/category/oranges, 345 54%, 432
/category/passion-fruit, 364, 23%, 475
```

As you can see, it checks input.csv against all values listed in output.txt to create corrected.csv.

Here's an example of what I'm getting instead:

```
corrected.csv
/category/apples, 500, 45%, 345
```

This issue was now resolved, however there's a new error now:

I now have a new issue. I made a counting program that does this:

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return (i + 1)
x = file_len("input.txt")
y = file_len("output.txt")
z = file_len("input.csv")
q = file_len("corrected.csv")
print ("input.txt: ", x)
print ("output.txt: ", y)
print ("input.csv: ", z)
print ("corrected.csv ", q)
user = input()
```

And now the counting program results in this:

```
input.txt - 2858
output.txt - 383
input.csv - 2853
corrected.csv - 321
```

What would account for the issue of the missing 62 that don't transfer from output.txt to corrected.csv?

Comment: I think it'd be nice to have a bit of example data from input.csv and output.txt, and what you expect the program out put to be vs what you are actually getting.

Comment: @waffleparadox Sure! I'm really sorry I didn't include it, I wasn't sure if it was needed. Edit right now.

Comment: What is incorrect about your current output, vs the corrected.csv that you posted?

Comment: It is, unlike what I want, only doing the first line rather than everything. I'm sorry, I just edited that in!

Comment: Regarding your latest edit (that you're missing 62 entries): Are you sure everything in `output.txt` is also in `input.csv`?  Also, what's `input.txt`?

Comment: Sorry, input.txt is used in a separate batch function I use to prepare output.txt (it scans them to see if there is a certain header -- this is somewhat unrelated). I'm positive everything in output.txt is in input.csv, also it puts them in corrected.csv in a weird order...

Comment: As John Y suggests, put in a bunch of print statements and examine them carefully to see what the program is doing vs. what you expect it to do.   You would go far toward answering the question "what would account for the missing 62" by poring over the print output and finding the first missing one.

Comment: I've gone through and it makes no sense. The lines array has all of the lines in correct order and the program works, so I don't get why it would ever go out of order... I've been working on this since last night and still no answer...

Comment: Well, the order of `corrected.csv` should depend on the order of `input.csv`, not on the order of `lines`.  Is `corrected.csv` in a different order than `input.csv`?  And are you still missing the 62 entries?

Comment: Figured it out. For some reason the .bat file I was using output a small message at the end of the text file - everything works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand - when I run the code, corrected.csv contains the first four lines out of five (apples, oranges, brussel-sprouts, zucchini).  It would have written the last line too (passion-fruit), except that when you read output.text you are deleting the last character leaving "passion-frui", which doesn't match.  Get rid of the [:-1] in line and use strip:

```
lines.append(line.strip())
```

Why do you expect corrected.csv to contain only apples, oranges, and passion-fruit.

Comment: Now they're not linking up. I have 383 elements in my output.txt but only 321 in my output.csv file... IT WORKED! (but not entirely)

Comment: @Dave: If you read some of his other recent questions surrounding this same problem, you'll see that his selector file (`output.txt` in this case) only has a subset of the "precorrected" input.  I think he's been experimenting a lot and just happened to miscopy the example used for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The example you've given works for me.  I wonder if you're facing a newline issue.  Instead of stripping off one character in each line of `output.txt`, try the `.strip()` method.  That is, instead of `line[:-1]`, use `line.strip()`.

If you're still having problems, try opening `input.csv` in `'rb'` mode instead of just `'r'`.

And if you're *still* having problems, then start putting in a lot of print statements and telling us what you see. ;)

Comment: But thank you very much for the help! It's working a lot better now than it was.